# Datagridview.DataPropertyName = System.Data.DataColumn.?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datacolumn, system.data

I have a list of columns

```
Dim ListCol As List(Of System.Data.DataColumn)
            For Each Col As System.Data.DataColumn In Grid.Columns
                ListCol.Add(Col)
            Next
```

I need the user friendly name of the columnl not the actual name of the column but the one displayed to the user.

```
Dim rr As Report.ReportRow() = Settings.Report.Select("rField = '" & ListCol.Item(i).DataPropertyName & "' AND rIsDefault = true")
```

I can't access the datapropertyname unless its a datagridview object. Im assumning I need to convert it to a datagridview but I was hoping to find a method of System.data.Datacolumn that would return the same text as if I asked for datagridview.DataPropertyName.

Comment: I don't want to have to convert the datacolumns to datagridviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're actually looking for [`System.Data.DataColumn.Caption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.caption.aspx). This lets you set a user-friendly name for the column.

Comment: This saved me time in changing all the captions on the DataGridView too, as I have been doing for too long. Thank you good sir.